# ffmpeg drawtext - Arabic fonts doesn't render correctly

Tags: ffmpeg, fonts, arabic

What I'm trying to achieve:

Loop an image into a video and overlay Arabic Text from the Qur'an on it including the text diacritical mark, using a custom font.

Example of the text to be rendered:

```
بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَـٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ
```

The font used:
https://fonts.qurancomplex.gov.sa/wp02/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/UthmanicHafs_v22.zip

Font's unicode module :

```
Unicode Module 
 
The Research and Development Unit in the Computer Department at King Fahd Glorious Qur’an Printing Complex relied on the unicode system unicode to create (Hafs) font in the Uthmanic Script, because this system is followed globally among computer and systems manufacturing companies in the world.

Unicode organization is a global code group that is used to define all codes and letters used in most of the world's languages and gathered in one code to facilitate the presentation and delivery on information despite of the language used. This global coding uses 1 to 4 bytes (byte = 8 bits) to encode letters, and so far only a third of the number available in Unicode organization to encode the letters of these languages.

Taking into account Hafs font with the Uthmanic Script, which was built entirely on the unicode system. We can explore the basic letters that were formed according to the following figure:

Whereas the font was developed starting from code (0600) to code (066FF), taking into account there are several encoded letters that haven't been used at all so they were replaced with the code []. The displayed copy above is the one that is been developed from the basic Arabic coding (0600-06FF) which was updated by Unicode organization in 2009.
```

Expected result:

Exported video with correctly rendered text using the given font.

Actual result:

The text rendered contains only the diacritical marks (which are the accents on top of the letters) without the actual letters.

[image: Result Image]

What I tried:

This is my test command which exports just an image for faster results:

```
Ffmpeg -loop 1  -i "image-2.jpg" -vf "drawtext=text='بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَـٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ':fontsize=124:fontcolor=white:fontfile='UthmanicHafsV22.ttf':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -frames:v 1  "output.png"
```

- tried adding `ft_load_flags`, almost tried all of them
- tried `text_shaping=1`, without success
- tried `textfile` instead of `text`
- tried changing the font, any font I try with it always have different problems, either some squares instead of the diacritical mark

PS -  I'm having the same results on both latest `ffmpeg` compiled by myself on MacOS terminal with all required libraries enabled, and also on `flutter ffmpeg kit full gpl`.

Comment: For me the same command you posted "seems" to work normaly on Windows: https://i.ibb.co/rHRTpnf/output.png